# How to detect layoutComplete when jQuery Masonry only positions one item?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm using Masonry to layout a number of articles, hiding everything at first and revealing items when layoutComplete fires. This works as planned when there are more than one article being positioned, but when one one is present, the layout remains hidden. I'm using Modernizr as well (seen in sass below).

Here's my code:

**CSS (SASS):**

```
.js-masonry, [data-masonry-options] {

    @include media-query(lap-and-up) {

        html.js & {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        html.js &.masonry-loaded {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var $container = $('.js-masonry').masonry();

$container.imagesLoaded( function() {

    $container.masonry({
        "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer",
        "gutter": ".gutter-sizer",
        "itemSelector": ".item",
        "percentPosition": true
    });

    $container.masonry('on', 'layoutComplete', function() {
        $container.addClass('masonry-loaded');
    });
});
```

Masonry if definitely adding inline styles to the single item, but layoutComplete isn't firing. Is there a trick to this, or have I discovered a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why my code wasn't working, though I suspect that between initializing masonry and attaching the onLayoutComplete event, it had already been fired. Falling back to a vanilla JS approach and attaching layoutComplete before calling the layout method fixed this issue for me.

```
var container = document.querySelector('.js-masonry');

var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer",
    "gutter": ".gutter-sizer",
    "itemSelector": ".item",
    "percentPosition": true
});

msnry.on('layoutComplete', function(laidOutItems) {
    container.className = 'masonry-loaded';
});

imagesLoaded( container, function() {
    msnry.layout();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not able to test this but try calling layoutcomplete outside of imagesloaded.

```
var $container = $('.js-masonry').masonry();

$container.imagesLoaded( function() {

$container.masonry({
    "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer",
    "gutter": ".gutter-sizer",
    "itemSelector": ".item",
    "percentPosition": true
});


});
$container.masonry('on', 'layoutComplete', function() {
    $container.addClass('masonry-loaded');
});
```

Comment: So close! We can't attach the the layoutComplete event outside of imagesLoaded because masonry hasn't been initialized. I decided to fallback to a vanilla js approach and it worked. See my answer for the solution.